# Issue while compiling make file for linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile, linux-kernel

I have just started with linux kernel development and I am having issue with compiling make file.

It is the tutorial of hello world.

My hello-1.c file

```
*
* hello−1.c − The simplest kernel module.
*/
#include <linux/module.h>
/* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>
/* Needed for KERN_INFO */
int init_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");
/*
* A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
*/
return 0;
}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

My Makefile

```
obj−m += hello−1.o

all:
        make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Both of this file are in folder /home/kkr/Documents/HelloWorld

When i run the make command I am getting below output.

```
uname: extra operand `−r'
Try `uname --help' for more information.
make −C /lib/modules//build M=/home/kkr/Documents/HelloWorld modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kkr/Documents/HelloWorld'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `−C'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kkr/Documents/HelloWorld'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can any body have any idea what is the root cause ? I know it is very simple still I am not able to come out from this ?

Thanks

Comment: Is that really the format of your `Makefile`? If it is, then the format is incorrect. Commands should be indented with a tab after the line that has the target and dependencies.

Comment: @mbratch No it is not. Actually while posting question I did ctrl+k may be that remove the tab. I have again edited the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(shell uname −r)
              ^
           This is not a - (dash , minus) character.
```

You want

```
$(shell uname -r)
```

Comment: Ohh ! nice observation and also I did the same thing in for C also. But I did it and also it compiles fine. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you find that out? Did you just see it?

Comment: @Étienne Just copy pasted it to a terminal to run uname −r , which failed, then typed the command myself which worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem initially.

The contents of Makefile shouldn't be copied.
The copying will change some characters so the 'make' command won't recognize them anymore.

To properly build the module, you need to manually type the code in Makefile.